# How do I center text vertically in a table cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I'm attempting my first Latex document.  I'm working on a header for some documents at work.  Being slightly overwhelmed by the complexity in general of tables, this vertical alignment issue is making things worse.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry,multirow,array}
    \geometry{
    letterpaper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=15mm,
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{6.25cm}|m{6.25cm}|} 
    \hline
    \multirow{6}{3cm}{logo here} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                 & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                 & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                 & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                 & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                 & & \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

The cell with the alphabet in it appears to align text to the top of the cell.  My header was much more complex than this, but I broke it down to this.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well with `c|` as the column specifier (in your `\multicolumn`) it will align at the top. To align in the middle, you'll probably wanna use `m` again

Comment: '\multicolumn{2}{m{12cm}|}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}' Produces a left/top aligned result.

Comment: I don't really see any difference in the vertical alignment with your minimal example, in fact I'm not sure how there could be, it might be necessary to expand your example to show all the relevant parts. For horizontal centering, for sure, you will need a `\centering` declaration. You will also need to specify a wide enough cell (12.92 cm in order to account for both 6.25 cm cells you are spanning and the 12 pt gap (6 pt either side) between columns). `\multicolumn{2}{m{12.92cm}|}{\centering ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}` Thinking about it, there probably is a better way to do this

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}}` strikes me as a good place to start, but it's hard to know without actually seeing what you're trying to build here. But, the `c` specifier was the reason, since it is top aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you are doing anything wrong.  `tabular` has some odd asymmetries with its line spacing (some people migrate to `booktabs` package as a result).  But, one can make manual adjustments.  Here I do two things:

1. I use `\addstackgap` to pad more vertical space above (and below) the text;
2. I use `\\[-3pt]` to negatively adjust the space below the entry.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,multirow,array,stackengine}
\geometry{
letterpaper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
top=15mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{6.25cm}|m{6.25cm}|} 
\hline
\multirow{6}{3cm}{logo here} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\addstackgap[4pt]{%
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}} \\[-3pt] \cline{2-3} 
                             & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                             & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                             & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                             & & \\ \cline{2-3}
                             & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using this solution.  I was looking for something simple.  This seems to be the path of least resistance.  Thank you!